# ModalPopup click twice when IFrame XPAD is on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, modal-dialog, modalpopupextender, xbap

I have a aspx page, with a modalpopup extender, and it's work perfect.
But I place an Iframe on the end of the page, and the modelpopup work only when I click the button twice. I can't find the answer for this problem.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="szamlabal14">
                        Csatlakozási pont:
                        <input type="hidden" id="hdnCsatlakozasiPontKod" runat="server" value="0" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCsatlakozasiPont" runat="server" Width="480" onkeydown="return false;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCsatlakozasiPont" runat="server" Text="..." />
                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeCsatlakozasiPont" runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                            TargetControlID="btnCsatlakozasiPont" OkControlID="btnOk" PopupControlID="pnPopup"
                            PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnPopup" Style="display: none" runat="server">
                            <div class="modalPopup">
                                <div style="position: relative; left: 670; margin: 3px;">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="x" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return false;" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" Style="display: none" CausesValidation="false"
                                        OnClientClick="return false;" />
                                </div>
                                <iframe id="ifrCsatlakozasiPont" height="350px" width="700px" src="CsatlakozasiPont.aspx"
                                    frameborder="1"></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I delete the following part, the modalpopup work well again.

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; z-index: 10; border: 1px solid black; position: absolute;
            top: 130px;">
            <iframe src="http://ismts38105/viewer/ImageViewer.xbap?<%=Image%> width="1440"
                height="400" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the permissions on your Internet Explorer. XBAP requires you add the domain/IP to the trusted sites, or else you will be unable to do anything with them.